# Using Tedit Inside of a FireMonkey component

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, custom-component

I have created a component in Fire-monkey and also created a TEdit inside it.
My component has a String Property named ***Value*** that by pouting any string to it , My Component will show that in Tedit.
at design Time every thing is OK. but at Run time no thing shows in Tedit 
My Code is

```
type
TMyComponent = class(TPanel)
private
  { Private declarations }
  Edit:TEdit;
  FValue:String;
  Procedure SetValue(Const Value:String);
protected
  { Protected declarations }
  Constructor Create(Aoner:TComponent); Override;
  Destructor Destroy; Override;
public
  { Public declarations }
published
  { Published declarations }
  Property Value:String Read FValue Write SetValue;
end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TMyComponent]);
end;

Constructor TMyComponent.Create(Aoner:TComponent);
begin
  Inherited;
  Width:=100;
  Height:=100;
  Edit:=TEdit.Create(Self);
  Edit.Parent:=Self;
  Edit.Width:=30;
  Edit.Text:='';
  Edit.Align:=TAlignLayout.Scale;
end;

Procedure TMyComponent.SetValue(const Value: string);
begin
  FValue:=Value;
  Edit.Text:=FValue;
end;

Destructor TMyComponent.Destroy;
begin
  Edit.Destroy;
  Inherited Destroy;
end;
end.
```

What Should I do?

Comment: Where is the code that you tested at run-time ?

Comment: look at the loaded

Comment: I can not reproduce whatever problem you have at runtime. Please try to improve your question with better explanation and add any missing code to your question.

Comment: I think by run-time he meant that if you drop this component and button on form and in button click event write `MyComponent1.Value := 'test'` value in component does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially I thought you were having problems both with creating and using your component at runtime. Instantiating and using your component at runtime works perfectly ok.

After the comment by EugeneK I now understand that the component doesn't work, if you instantiate it at design time and attempt to change the text property of the `TEdit` at runtime.

The reason can be traced to the fact that your component is a composed type and constructed from subcomponents (well, only a `TEdit`). If the `Stored` property of the subcomponent(s) are not set to `False` they might get streamed several times at design time, f.ex. when you switch between form view and text view of the form.

See [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/FireMonkey_Component_Design) and scroll down to **TCalender: Constructed Complexity** where you can find the following:

> Every object in the component tree has its Stored property set to
>   False and its Locked property set to True. Disabling Stored prevents
>   the object from being streamed out to the .fmx file by the Form
>   Designer. If the Stored property is not disabled, subcomponents would
>   be redundantly created when loading.

The result after switching the form view to text view twice:

```
  object MyComponent1: TMyComponent
    Position.X = 8.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 8.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 100.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 100.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 5
    object TEdit
      Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
      Align = Scale
      TabOrder = 1
      Size.Width = 90.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 18.333332061767580000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
    end
    object TEdit
      Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
      Align = Scale
      TabOrder = 0
      Size.Width = 90.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 18.333332061767580000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
    end
  end
```

while this is how it should look like:

```
  object MyComponent1: TMyComponent
    Position.X = 8.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 8.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 100.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 100.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 5
  end
```

The redundant `TEdit` controls will cover the one you create in the constructor.

The **correction** to your code:
Add the marked line

```
constructor TMyComponent.Create(Aoner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  Width:=100;
  Height:=100;
  Edit:=TEdit.Create(Self);
  Edit.Parent:=Self;
  Edit.Width:=90;
  Edit.Align:=TAlignLayout.Scale;
  Edit.Stored := False;  // *** add this line ***
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to do this kind of things using styles in FireMonkey, so for your example you need `MyComponent.style` file as following

```
object TRectangle
  StyleName = 'MyComponentStyle'
  Align = Center
  Fill.Color = xFFF0F0F0
  HitTest = False
  Size.Width = 159.000000000000000000
  Size.Height = 131.000000000000000000
  Size.PlatformDefault = False
  Stroke.Color = xFFCCCCCC
  object TEdit
    StyleName = 'MyComponentEditStyle'
    Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
    Align = Scale
    TabOrder = 0
    Size.Width = 79.499755859375000000
    Size.Height = 21.833337783813480000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
  end
end
```

then you need to include `MyComponent.rc` in the project file as following

```
MyComponentStyle RCDATA  "MyComponent.style"
```

and your `MyComponent.pas` will be

```
unit MyComponent;

interface

uses System.Classes, FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Edit, FMX.Styles;

type
  TMyComponent = class(TPanel)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FEdit: TEdit;
    FValue: string;
    procedure SetValue(const AValue: string);
    function GetValue: string;
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    procedure FreeStyle; override;
    procedure ApplyStyle; override;
    function GetStyleObject: TFmxObject; override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    { Published declarations }
    property Value: string read GetValue write SetValue;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

uses Winapi.Windows;

{$R MyComponent.res}

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TMyComponent]);
end;

procedure TMyComponent.ApplyStyle;
begin
  inherited;
  if FindStyleResource<TEdit>('MyComponentEditStyle', FEdit) then
  begin
    FEdit.Visible := True;
    FEdit.Text := Value;
  end;
end;

function TMyComponent.GetStyleObject: TFmxObject;
const
  Style = 'MyComponentStyle';
begin
  if (StyleLookup = '') then
    Result := TStyleStreaming.LoadFromResource(HInstance, Style, RT_RCDATA)
  else
    Result := inherited GetStyleObject;
end;

procedure TMyComponent.FreeStyle;
begin
  FEdit := nil;
  inherited;
end;

constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  Width := 100;
  Height := 100;
end;

procedure TMyComponent.SetValue(const AValue: string);
begin
  FValue := AValue;
  if Assigned(FEdit) then
  begin
    FEdit.Text := FValue;
  end;
end;

function TMyComponent.GetValue: string;
begin
  Result := FValue;
end;

end.
```